# What do I have to do to solve this equation correctly and print its respective graph?

Tags: python, math, graphics, equation, ode

I manually solved the equation below and already found its respective result. However, I have no idea how to apply it in python. What would I have to do? I thought of the below code but it is giving **invalid syntax**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

# Datas
w1 = 400 #kg/min
w2 = 200 #kg/min
x1 = 0.4
x2 = 0.75
v = 2
rho = 900 #kg/m3

# Solving the equation

def mydiff(x, t):

    dx1dt = ((rho)*(v))/((w1)+(w2)) dx/dt + x = ((w1)*(x1))+((w2)*(x2))/(w1+w2)
    
    dxdt = [dx1dt]
    return dxdt

# solving the ODE
x = odeint(mydiff, t)

x1 = x[:,0]

# Ploting
plt.plot(t,x)
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('x(t)')
plt.legend(["x"])
plt.grid()
plt.show
```

I thought of the code above to apply in python, however, it did not work. I was hoping that it would print the correct result, but unfortunately I couldn't. What do I have to do to get this right?

Comment: You have `dx/dt` just sitting out on its own. Do you mean to multiply something by it? Or is it referring to a derivative? Assuming it's the latter, that's not how that works at all. You're literally dividing something called `dx` by something called `dt`. That's not how derivatives work. Plus, you're setting a whole statement equal to another statement on that line, which makes no sense. You're writing down mathematical language as if Python understands it, but Python is only going to do the basic operations like multiplication and addition. Solving an equation is a whole other thing.

Comment: If you want to solve equations in Python you can use something like [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) which has a solver. But yeah, you can't just throw in fancy math terms like "dy/dx" and expect Python to magically know you're doing a derivative. It has no idea what a derivative is. It just thinks you're trying to divide the variable called `dx` by the value of the variable called `dt`. You're giving it way too much credit.

Comment: Please add the differential equation as close as possible to a mathematical formula. You can use code fences with "lang-none" to prevent the random coloring of parts of the formula.